# magento 2 with separate node of elasticsearch with oracle cloud infrastructure

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, magento2, aws-elasticsearch, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have gone through this article. however, it is quite old but I have a a simple question. will Magento 2 support this terraform?

https://blogs.oracle.com/cloud-infrastructure/deploying-elasticsearch-on-oracle-cloud-infrastructure-using-a-terraform-template

but as per dev doc https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/bk-cloud.html

how we can alternate this elastic search of Magento with terraform template of oci ?

EDIT

I tried to install in AWS ec2 with RDS and a sparate node with AWS elasticsearch while i issued :

curl "url of elasticsearch"

it returned perfect output but

bin/magento install command did not accept remote elasticsearch.
so how we can do it in the OCI.

ES: 7.6.0
Magento 2.4.4
php 7.4
ubuntu 20.4 or oracle autonomous linux.
ES we want to keep with GCP as well.

magento link :

thanks
sayantan

the latest community installation with composer param the param --elasticsearch-host can not detect the deployed elasticsearch if host is not locahost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you be more explicit ?
You can customize the Terraform deployment to deploy ES.
Magento2 does not support Elasticsearch 2.x, 5.x, and 6.x but this Terraform deploy ES 7.0 and you can still customize it.